# Link an existing java file with Swing Designer

Tags: java, eclipse

I've a Java source file which I've created in eclipse.  After this I installed Swing Designer. How can I link the file to the swing designer. That is, If i create a file using the options in swing designer I can use the palette  and other stuff. I want these tools and the design view available for the file which I created before installing Swing or the files that have been created without the Designers options at first and now need them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to open the file with the WindowBuilder editor: Right click on the file, and select Open with/WindowBuilder editor.

Then select the Design tab during editing, and you can hopefully edit your form - no specific registration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Zoltán's solution but I found that I needed to force eclipse to always open .java files with the WindowBuilder editor.

Right click on the file, Open With > Other > Window Builder

Make sure you check *Use it for all '.java' files*